# Тройка: "задан", "изменен", "отвечен"

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

"Вопрос задан. Вопрос/ответ изменен." тут всё понятно и привычно.

А вот "Ответ *отвечен*" режет слух.

Может быть лучше использовать "Ответ *написан*" или что-то подобное?
ПС. Ну и так как площадка на русском языке, то было бы неплохо и про русскую букву Ё не забывать: "Вопрос/ответ измен**ё**н".

Comment: Ну, обычно ответ _дают_. А в каком контексте вы нашли форму «Ответ отвечен»?

Comment: "Ответ дан" как-то тоже не то. Да под каждым ответом написано над логином автора (пример. "отвечен 1 час назад")

Answer (score 4):

Исправил букву «ё» в двух десятках строк с «изменён», «изменённый» и т.п.

Заменил «отвечен» на «опубликован». Ответ опубликован тогда-то.

[Tx:2748](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264534?key=2098fbcec3eae9669bcd1ad15b2ba1a5)

> answered $when$
>
> опубликован $when$

[Tx:4080](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265944?key=6a5747cf38d953c321b35f58e31df4b5)

> answered $date$
>
> опубликован $date$

При желании можно предлагать другие варианты, проголосуем за лучший.

Comment: Очень хороший вариант — «опубликован».